# PHP Login with differerent user level

Tags: php, sql

I'm creating a login with different user level. How to get the user_level field fom my table users to comapare if the username and password is admin or staff.

Here's the code:

```
<?php
include("../config/database.php");

if(isset($_POST["login"]))
{
  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];

  $username = stripslashes($username);
  $password = stripslashes($password);
  $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
  $password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);

  $query = "SELECT * FROM users 
                     WHERE username= '$username' OR email= '$username'  
                           AND password='$password'";
  $result = mysql_query($query);

  $count = mysql_num_rows($result);//counting table rows

  if($count==1)
  {//check if found username and password
    if(user_level == "admin")
    {
      header("Location: ../views/admin/dashboard.php");
    }
    elseif(user_level=="patient")
    {
      header("Location: ../views/default/home.php");
    }

  }
  else
  {
    echo "WRONG USERNAME OR PASSWORD!";
  }

}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make few changes , it wil work...

```
$count = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
```

and also

```
if($count==1){//check if found username and password
        if($count['user_level'] == "admin"){
            header("Location: ../views/admin/dashboard.php");
        }elseif($count['user_level']=="patient"){
            header("Location: ../views/default/home.php");
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(user_level == "admin"){
```

should be

```
$record=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
if($record["user_level"] == "admin"){
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all try to separate using parentheses

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users
        WHERE (username= '$username' OR email= '$username')  
        AND password='$password'";";
```

And also `mysql_*` functions are depricated. You can use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` for that matter.

And to answer your question, do you have a field that determines the role of the user in your table? if so simply return the field and check if the user is the appropriate role.

Example:

```
$data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

if ($data["user_level"] == "admin" ){
   ...
}
```

Comment: This is my connection to the database
$conn= mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password) or die("ERROR". mysql_error);
  $db= mysql_select_db($database) or die("ERROR" .mysql_error);

do i have to change it to mysqli?

Answer (score 0):

You should add a field `user_level` in Database table `users`. You can assign it value `admin` or `patient` at registration level.

After that, use the same query with a new variable `$previlage`. Then use it to fetch contents from database, Like below,,,

```
           $previlage=mysql_fetch_array($result); //fetch contents from db

            if($previlage['user_level'] == "admin"){
                header("Location: ../views/admin/dashboard.php"); // if userlevel admin
            }elseif($previlage['user_level']=="patient"){
                header("Location: ../views/default/home.php"); // if user level is patient
            }
```